# What will be the probability density function of a function of the random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

This question just came to my mind while thinking in the shower, and it's answer too will if I think hard enough but I would like to get the answer lot quicker by sharing it with you.

So, let's say X is some random variable, whose range is from say 0 to 1.
And let's say it follows some, probability distribution function, let us assume that it is a rectangular one for the sake of simplicity. So the probability of obtaining any number will be equal and exhaustive and mutually exclusive. i.e. 1/100.

Now let's say we introduced a function of X, f(X) = x*100 to increase the range from 0 to 1 to 0 to 100
This will make no change to the probability density function of f(X). i.e., f(X) will also have a rectangular distribution.

But now, if we want to increase the range of the random variable from 0 to 100 to 0 to 200 but I want to do it by defining the third random variable g(X) as
g(X) = x*100 + 100

instead of doing x*200, what will happen to the probability distribution of g(X)?

EDIT: I just read that a thing called skewness also exists so is it related to something like that?

Comment: oh... hahaha idk what made me think 100*x + 100 will have a range of [0,200] lol thank you for correcting me out and sorry for wasting your time with a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

*Moving comments to answer:*

It is not related to [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness), which is scale and location invariant.

Your $g(x)=100x+100$ will produce a distribution in the interval $[100,200]$ while $200x$ would produce a distribution in the interval $[0,200]$.

So $g(x)$ would have a higher expectation and lower dispersion than the alternative.